# Removing duplicate values in Python dictionaries?

Tags: python

More a concept question than a direct coding one. But say I had a dictionary akin to this one.

```
Dict = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'E':1}
Dict2 = {}
```

And I wanted to take all instances were two keys had the same value, and put them in a different dictionary, what sort of process be the most efficient? I've tried measures like

```
for value in Dict.items()
        for a in value:
            if a != b:
                continue
            else:
                Dict2.append(a)
                continue
```

But to no luck.

Comment: Make a reverse dictionary, where the keys are the numeric values in this dict, and the values in the new dict are lists of the keys that had that value. - you build that, and then you can iterate over it looking for values in the dict (lists) that have a length > 1.  That list will contain the keys in the original dict that had the same value, now the key for that entry in the new list.

Comment: What should your code do if all keys had the same value?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Dict = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'E':1}
result = {}

for k, v in Dict.items():
    result.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)

print("Original: ")
print(Dict)

print("------------")

print("Result: ")
print(result)
```

> Original:
>
> {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 1}
>
> ---
>
> Result:
>
> {1: {'A', 'E'}, 3: {'B', 'C'}, 4: {'D'}}

Answer (score 0):

Old school, with regular loops.  Could maybe be done with list or dict comprehensions, but this is easy and obvious:

```
dict = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'E':1}

# Make a reverse dictionary that maps values to lists of keys
# that have that value in the original dict
reverse_dict = {}
for k, v in dict.items():
    reverse_dict.setdefault(v, list()).append(k)

# Show the reverse dict
# print(reverse_dict)

# Move entries for keys that had duplicates from the original
# dict to a new dict
dups_dict = {}
for k, vs in reverse_dict.items():
    if len(vs) > 1:           # if there was more than one key with this value
        for v in vs:          # for each of those keys
            dups_dict[v] = k  # copy it to the new dict
            del dict[v]       # and remove it from the original dict

# Show the original dict and the new one
print(dict)
print(dups_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'D': 4}
{'A': 1, 'E': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}
```